# Linux mint 21.1 resumes immediately after suspend

Tags: linux-mint, suspend

i recently installed linux mint 21.1 in my desktop, but i've been having problems with suspend, the computer resumes immediately after suspend, i already checked and wake on lan is disabled in my bios, this is the cat /proc/acpi/wakeup output:

```
GP12      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
GP13      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
XHC0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:08:00.3
GP30      S4    *disabled
GP31      S4    *disabled
PS2K      S3    *disabled
PS2M      S3    *disabled
GPP0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.1
GPP8      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:03.1
PTXH      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:02:00.0
PT20      S4    *disabled
PT23      S4    *disabled
PT24      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:03:04.0
PT26      S4    *disabled
PT27      S4    *disabled
PT28      S4    *disabled
PT29      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:03:09.0
```

Devices:

```
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
08:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
02:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ee
03:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43ea
```

inxi -G output:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA104 [GeForce RTX 3070 Lite Hash Rate] driver: nvidia
    v: 525.85.05
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia resolution:
    1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.85.05
```

Here is /var/log/syslog

```
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 ModemManager[1239]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617141.2079] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617141.2080] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617141.2080] device (enp5s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 dbus-daemon[1146]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=0 pid=1147 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12554.501805] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 dbus-daemon[1146]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617141.2346] device (enp5s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 avahi-daemon[1142]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::5f7b:335a:6ec0:e336 on enp5s0.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 avahi-daemon[1142]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp5s0.IPv6 with address fe80::5f7b:335a:6ec0:e336.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 avahi-daemon[1142]: Interface enp5s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617141.2354] dhcp4 (enp5s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617141.2354] dhcp4 (enp5s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617141.2354] dhcp4 (enp5s0): state changed no lease
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 avahi-daemon[1142]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.100.28 on enp5s0.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 avahi-daemon[1142]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp5s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.100.28.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 avahi-daemon[1142]: Interface enp5s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-resolved[1074]: enp5s0: Bus client set default route setting: no
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617141.2373] device (enp5s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-resolved[1074]: enp5s0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12554.532319] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 org.cinnamon.ScreenSaver[18359]: Successfully using logind
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 cinnamon-session[1489]: WARNING: t+12523.46707s: Detected that screensaver has appeared on the bus
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 logger[18436]: <13>Mar 23 18:19:01 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 23 18:19:01 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Mar 23 18:19:02 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 23 18:19:02 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Mar 23 18:19:02 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Mar 23 18:19:02 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-sleep[18451]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.597604] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.599183] Filesystems sync: 0.001 seconds
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.599325] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.600881] OOM killer disabled.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.600882] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.100 seconds) done.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.701738] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.725441] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.725456] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.725456] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.725544] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.725552] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12555.725952] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Stopping disk
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.485638] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.829942] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.829992] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.831744] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.834000] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.836118] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.838272] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.840273] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.842335] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.844229] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.846131] smpboot: CPU 8 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.846646] Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP off
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.848008] smpboot: CPU 9 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.849843] smpboot: CPU 10 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.851520] smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.853307] smpboot: CPU 12 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.855024] smpboot: CPU 13 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.856675] smpboot: CPU 14 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.858334] smpboot: CPU 15 is now offline
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.859184] ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.859201] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.859345] LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.859873] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.859909] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.859909] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.860012] microcode: CPU1: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.863105] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C002: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.866157] CPU1 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.866176] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.866278] microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.868431] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C004: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.870157] CPU2 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.870173] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.870261] microcode: CPU3: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.872414] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C006: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.874206] CPU3 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.874219] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x8
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.874308] microcode: CPU4: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.876459] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C008: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.878179] CPU4 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.878192] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0xa
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.878282] microcode: CPU5: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.880438] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00A: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.882194] CPU5 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.882209] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0xc
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.882299] microcode: CPU6: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.884459] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00C: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.886214] CPU6 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.886226] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0xe
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.886318] microcode: CPU7: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.888481] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00E: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.890232] CPU7 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.890244] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x1
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.890365] microcode: CPU8: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.892529] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C001: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.894297] Spectre V2 : Update user space SMT mitigation: STIBP always-on
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.894301] CPU8 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.894324] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x3
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.894415] microcode: CPU9: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.896573] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C003: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.898313] CPU9 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.898326] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0x5
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.898420] microcode: CPU10: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.900577] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C005: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.902323] CPU10 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.902336] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0x7
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.902430] microcode: CPU11: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.904583] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C007: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.906351] CPU11 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.906365] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 12 APIC 0x9
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.906458] microcode: CPU12: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.908612] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C009: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.910386] CPU12 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.910399] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 13 APIC 0xb
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.910496] microcode: CPU13: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.912651] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00B: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.914420] CPU13 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.914434] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 14 APIC 0xd
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.914533] microcode: CPU14: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.916690] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00D: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.918454] CPU14 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.918467] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 15 APIC 0xf
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.918572] microcode: CPU15: patch_level=0x0a201016
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.920731] ACPI: \_SB_.PLTF.C00F: Found 2 idle states
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.922477] CPU15 is up
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12556.923924] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.018658] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.018659] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Starting disk
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.018660] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Starting disk
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.019232] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.019233] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.019234] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.046610] nvme nvme0: 32/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.102714] nvme nvme1: 32/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.330465] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 330)
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.330501] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.450802] usb 1-3: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.490224] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.491549] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12557.806751] usb 1-5: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.058199] ata6: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.058212] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.162675] usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.518726] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.690199] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.723016] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.750210] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.771654] OOM killer enabled.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.771655] Restarting tasks ... done.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.774594] PM: suspend exit
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.775288] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Setting up dongle with HCI ver=6 rev=22bb; LMP ver=6 subver=22bb; manufacturer=10
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-resolved[1074]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_hq
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-sleep[18451]: System returned from sleep state.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_sq
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_mq
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx_hd
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_hd
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1472]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth Support.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth Support.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1472]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12558.784379] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
Mar 23 18:19:05 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 pulseaudio[1481]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_hq
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_sq
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/ldac_mq
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx_hd
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_hd
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 bluetoothd[1144]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.46 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 dbus-daemon[1146]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.blueman.Mechanism' unit='blueman-mechanism.service' requested by ':1.76' (uid=1000 pid=2803 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet " label="unconfined")
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 dbus-daemon[1146]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.blueman.Mechanism'
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-sleep[18624]: /dev/sdb:
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-sleep[18624]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-sleep[18624]:  APM_level#011= 254
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-sleep[18646]: /dev/sdc:
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-sleep[18646]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd-sleep[18646]:  APM_level#011= 0
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12559.434006] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-500:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-500:00, irq=MAC)
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617146.5453] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 ModemManager[1239]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617146.5453] device (enp5s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system resume actions...
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 logger[18741]: <13>Mar 23 18:19:06 suspend: nvidia-resume.service
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: nvidia-resume.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system resume actions.
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 acpid: client 1336[0:0] has disconnected
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 acpid: client connected from 1336[0:0]
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 NetworkManager[1147]: <info>  [1679617146.7749] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar 23 18:19:06 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 kernel: [12559.634084] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
Mar 23 18:19:08 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 com.docker.backend[2828]: [2023-03-24T00:19:08.916309120Z][com.docker.backend][W] still waiting to update HTTP proxy on http-proxy-control.sock after 3h28m49.538949868s. Last error was Post "http://localhost/http_proxy.json": dial unix http-proxy-control.sock: connect: no such file or directory
Mar 23 18:19:09 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 ModemManager[1239]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.2/0000:03:09.0/0000:05:00.0': not supported by any plugin
Mar 23 18:19:10 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 cinnamon-screensaver-pam-helper: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Mar 23 18:19:10 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: systemd-rfkill.service: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 23 18:19:11 quevon24-B550-GAMING-X-V2 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

I'm not a linux expert, but if anyone can help me i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is specifically related to AMD PCI bridge device from a B550 motherboard which if disabled in /proc/acpi/wake, address the problem and PC sleeps well.

To solve the problem i created this script: ~/scripts/disable-devices-as-wakeup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a devices=(GPP0) # <-- Add your entries here
for device in "${devices[@]}"; do
    if grep -qw ^$device.*enabled /proc/acpi/wakeup; then
        sudo sh -c "echo $device > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
        echo "Device disabled: $device"
    fi
done
```

then in terminal:

```
sudo chmod + ~/scripts/disable-devices-as-wakeup.sh

touch ~/scripts/disable-devices-as-wakeup.service
```

in the text editor i created this service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable devices as wakeup

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/username/scripts/disable-devices-as-wakeup.sh
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

run in terminal:

```
sudo cp ~/scripts/disable-devices-as-wakeup.service /etc/systemd/system/
systemctl enable disable-devices-as-wakeup.service
```

Comment: I have this board and am also on 21.1 but where do I find my entries to put in place of GPP0?

Comment: You need to run in the terminal: cat /proc/acpi/wakeup

Comment: It's a bit later, am having the same response to suspending - immediately waking up.  I imagine its the same problem, but hard & software are a little different: B650 board and Mint 21.3 ... think the same solution will work? Is it a safe try: I'd hate to hose the whole installation over one issue!

Comment: it may work, you need to check the output of /proc/acpi/wakeup to know which devices can wake up your pc, and disable the correct one